# How to partition 32G SD card with 6 sda# drives to max memory usage - Raspberry / Ubuntu

Tags: sd-card, ubuntu, memory, partition

I am only a beginner at Linux-OS's so take this into consideration when you answer this question.  I have noticed that my 32G SD card is partitioned into two sda# drives but I need to max out this device for 3D designs and I would like to partition the 32G SD into 6 sda# drives where 1=>2 are as formatted, but 4=>6 are different sizes(3.5,4,8,16). Is this possible.

Comment: You can add partitions, or re-partition your card. **HOWEVER** this will **NOT** "max" anything, and does not seem like a good idea. You should post the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` (into your question - not as a comment) and explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely partition the SD as you desire. You will need [`gparted`](http://gparted.org/) to accomplish your goal.

Use `gparted` to create an extended partition. Inside the extended partition, create as many logical partitions as you need.

You can only use `gparted` to modify unmounted partitions. If you are going to use your Raspberry Pi to modify the SD card, you will need a second SD card to boot from and an SD card reader for the 32 GB SD card.

Make sure that all partitions on the 32 GB SD card are unmounted by looking at the output of `mount`. You can use `fdisk -l` and `blkid` to identify which card is the 32 GB SD card.

Comment: David Cullen:  Thank you for your time and knowledge! *****

Comment: @DCBradley: If this answer solved your problem, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks again.  I hope I voted correctly!   Uum I guess others that add comments also have the chance to vent too.  Take Care Dave!  You are a knowledgeable person and helpful.